# taking play framework object in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, playframework

I have a map declared in template parameters with the following syntax

```
@(formData : scala.collection.Map[String, scala.List[String]], previousData : scala.collection.Map[String,String], resultList: scala.List[String])(implicit flash: play.api.mvc.Flash)
```

I want to read the previousData map object and want to store it in a javascript variable. 
I actually want to set the value in a textbox by fetching the value from the map object. I know that I can use document.getElementById in javascript to set the value of a particular textbox. Could anyone please help? If some other way is possible please let me know. 
I tried the following method but it isn't working.

```
function loadPreviousData()
{
    if(@previousData != null)
    {
         var x = @{previousData.getOrElse("name",null)};
         alert("Name is " +x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to directly solve this, but there's a method which worked for me and so I'm sharing.

I used a Json object instead of a Map to tackle this. The required data in the key value format was filled in JSON object and passed that JSON object in the form of a String using toString() method.

```
Ok(views.html.serviceReplay.render(formData, resultList.toList, fetchFormDataInJson.toString,newFlash))
```

In the view section, this Json object was obtained as a string.

```
@(formData : scala.collection.Map[String, scala.List[String]], resultList: scala.List[String], previousPageData : String)(implicit flash: play.api.mvc.Flash)
```

And finally, in order to obtain in a variable at the view section, following instruction was used.

```
var previousDataInJson = JSON.parse('@previousPageData'.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'));
```

This worked for me. Hope it helps others.

Additionally, if we want to do via Map object I found a solution to that as well.

I was unable to directly use @formData directly in the javascript code, but it worked in the HTML section, therefore I used in the following scenario.

```
<select name="service" id="service">
                        <option value="">Select Service</option>
                        @for(serviceName <- formData.getOrElse("service",null)) {
                            <option value="@serviceName">@serviceName</option>
                        }
                    </select>
```

Now the value has been assigned to the serviceName, therefore, this can be easily retrieved using JQuery using the following syntax.

```
var service = $("#service").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use JQuery which is widely used nowadays. Let's say txtname is the id of your textbox then you can do like this

```
$("#txtname").val(x);
```

Here x is the variable in which you extracts the data.

Comment: I have already tried this. Without play framework, it works perfectly fine. But I need this as a working module in play. It doesn't work there.

Comment: Firstly you need to convert your scala map object to json in javascript through this    var info=@Html(Json.toJson(previousData.toMap));  then iterate that object and set the value in the textbox.